# remove event listener via jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-handling, dom-events

Does anybody know how to remove event listener attached by 3rd party script?

[image: situation]

I've highlighted the event attached to my object in the above image. When I inspect element and click on **Remove** button in chrome's Development Tool - event is deleted. I would like to achive the same results using jQuery or pure JS.

Best regards.

Comment: You can only use jQuery to remove events that were added via jQuery. To do it in your case just call `$(document).off('keydown')`. If it was added natively use `document.removeEventListener();`, but you'll need to provide a reference to the handler function.

Comment: And if an anonymous function was added with `addEventListener()`, there's no way to remove it from JS.